# verify if a <asp:ContentPlaceHolder exist in page via js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

in the master page there is a `ContentPlaceHolder`

### page.Master:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadLastPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
```

is it possible through **external** `JS` file to verify if it exist on page?

something like,

### external.js:

```
var HeadLastPlaceHolder = document.getElementById("HeadLastPlaceHolder");
if(HeadLastPlaceHolder != null){
// exist
}else{ 
// not exist
}
```

Comment: I don't think they get rendered so you won't be able to find it with js, what you could do is put a span inside the content placeholder and then see if that exists

Comment: You won't be able to do that. ASP.NET renders no HTML for a ContentPlaceHolder

Answer (score 0):

The short answer for content placeholder ID search in client-side is **no**.

Based from my tests, with default `ClientID` configuration you can retrieve a content placeholder name using `this.[ContentPlaceHolderName].ClientID` inside master page markup like this example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // returns 'HeadLastPlaceHolder'
    var HeadLastPlaceHolder = "<%= this.HeadLastPlaceHolder.ClientID %>";
    if(HeadLastPlaceHolder != null) {
        // content placeholder exists
    }
    else {
        // content placeholder doesn't exist
    }
</script>
```

However if you want to use `document.getElementById` with `ClientID` retrieved above, it will return `null` since no HTML element in page matches with that placeholder name, an expected behavior of [`ContentPlaceHolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.contentplaceholder(v=vs.110).aspx) class as described below:

> A ContentPlaceHolder control *defines a relative region for content* in
>   a master page, and renders all text, markup, and server controls from
>   a related Content control found in a content page.

When handling master pages, contents of individual `asp:Content` controls will merge into corresponding `asp:ContentPlaceHolder` controls, and merged result renders in client's browser. Hence, no HTML markup is generated for `ContentPlaceHolder` itself, it contains markup from `asp:Content` instead (see [Master Pages Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.100).aspx)).

Of course you can't retrieve content placeholder ID which doesn't actually exist, because it will throwing error like this:

> ASP.site_master does not contain a definition for
>   [ContentPlaceHolderName] ...

Comment: ok. thanks for that. but in my case for external `js` file it won't work.